# How to get an mp3 or wave file from Java program without knowing the name and url of the file?

Tags: java, file, url, audio, mp3

I have created a Mediaplayer in Java .. It can Play both `.mp3` and `.wav` files ..

I create its setup installer and install MediaPlayer on my computer... Then I set My MediaPlayer as a default program for Audio files on my computer... Now Problem is that when I open an audio file on my computer it opens my MediaPlayer because it is default program for audio files but MediaPlayer Does not know how to get or capture that audio file in order to play it ..
What type of code I have to add in MediaPlayer to get that Audio file?

Otherwise my MediaPlayer works cool, it has a brows Button on GUI, by clicking that button one can brows a song on computer and MediaPlayer will play that song.

I tried many things as:

```
String name=getClass().getName();
URL url=getClass().getResource(name);
```

.... Blaaa Blaaaa etc...

At last I found my self unable to solve that problem...

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275310/how-can-my-java-program-be-used-to-open-a-file-when-the-file-is-double-clicked) may help

Comment: I'm assuming that you're double click the audio files and the is is running your program, in which case it will be passed to your main method as one of the programs arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the path of the file as argument to your main method, when you declare your main method :

```
public static void Main(String[] args){
    args[0] // contains the path of the opened file.
}
```